# MATLAB: Importing data into Matlab from an Excel Sheet with 100,000 rows and 300 columns

Tags: excel, matlab, import, data-analysis

I have a huge data that comes in an excel file of about 100,000 rows and 300 columns. I'd like to import this data into Matlab to do some analysis.

Basicly, xlsread command does not work. 
Does anyone know how to effectively import this data into Matlab?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [readtable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)?

Comment: What does "command does not work" mean? Can you provide error messages?

Comment: I am using Matlab R2011a and it seems like that does not exist in this version!

Comment: Yes, MATLAB tables (along with readtable) was introduced in R2013b. If you have the statistics toolbox you may want to look at dataset.

Comment: I typed xlsread command and executed. After waiting more than 2 hours, Matlab couldn't upload the file. I don't know whether it is a matter of time or something else.

Comment: If this is a one-off analysis, you could open the file in Excel and save it in a friendlier format like a comma or tab delimited text and then use `dlmread` or `textscan` to read in the file (and if you don't have Excel, you can use something like LibreOffice). This is, of course, less than satisfying if you have many different files. In my experience, `xlsread` is incredibly slow and should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side - is the format of the file xls or xlsx? The xls is specified to have a maximum of 65,536 rows by 256 columns.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12174), by [@Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180721/oleg-komarov), it should be possible to read and store the file block by block.

This can be done by using the range input argument as mentioned in the [doc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html):

```
num = xlsread(filename,xlRange)example
num = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange)example
num = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange,'basic')
```

I would say start with 1 row first, and then see whether you can do a few thousand.